# Modelica fluid mixing simulation

Tags: fluid, modelica, openmodelica

I am newbie to modelica.

I am searching for people having experience with (open)modelica regarding fluid and media library.

My goal  is to simulate pressure of a volume related to injection flows of N2 and H2 and controlled outlet valve but also time varying mass fraction ( due to very large volume compared to flow injection / outlet capacity )
Thanks for any feedback.
I have a more detailed explanation of my project that I can can share in private.

Up to now I only tried to create a new medium for HNx ( H2N2) from media library using idealgases NasaGasMixture

My main problem is that modelica unit for flow is Kg/s and our industrial practice is Nm3/h ( same for H2 contraction ( molar fraction) related to mass fraction
I found molartomassfraction function in the library but do not see how to use this properly to modify the interface using our usual units( for display of measurement, setpoint, but also curves )

Answer (score 1):

The equations in `Modelica.Fluid` are all formulated with *masses* so you will have to do the conversion to and from chemical units (normal flow and molar fractions) "outside" the `Modelica.Fluid` components.

I have provided an example where you can vary normal flow and molar fractions of a mixture of N2/H2. Diagram, selected results and code is provided below. All the conversion blocks to the left can, of course, be written in code and/or wrapped nicely in a submodel.

**Diagram**
[image: Diagram view]

**Selected results**
[image: Selected results]

**Medium model**

```
package MixtureGas "Mixture gas"
  extends Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.MixtureGasNasa(
    mediumName="MixtureGas",
    data={Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.SingleGasesData.N2,Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.SingleGasesData.H2},
    fluidConstants={Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.FluidData.N2,Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.FluidData.H2},
    substanceNames={"N2","H2"},
    reference_X={0.4,0.6});
end MixtureGas;
```

**Simulation Model**

```
model Mixing "Molar fractions and normal flow as independent inputs"
  extends Modelica.Icons.Example;
  package Medium = MixtureGas;

  parameter Medium.AbsolutePressure p_normal=Medium.p_default "Normal pressure";
  parameter Medium.Temperature T_normal=273.15 "Normal temperature";
  Medium.Density rho_normal=Medium.density_pTX(
      p_normal,
      T_normal,
      X) "Normal density of mixture";

  // Conversion from mole to mass fractions 
  Real X[Medium.nX]=Medium.moleToMassFractions(moleFractions=moleFractions.y,
      MMX=Medium.data.MM) "Mass fraction vector {N2, H2}";

  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T source(
    use_m_flow_in=true,
    use_X_in=true,
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    nPorts=1)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-60,-10},{-40,10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT boundary1(nPorts=1, redeclare package
      Medium = Medium)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{140,-10},{120,10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume volume(
    use_portsData=false,
    V=0.1,
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    nPorts=2) annotation (Placement(transformation(
        extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
        rotation=0,
        origin={-10,20})));
  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system(energyDynamics=Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-140,80},{-120,100}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.MassFractionsTwoPort massFraction_H2(redeclare package
      Medium = Medium, substanceName="H2")
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{10,-10},{30,10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.MassFractionsTwoPort massFraction_N2(redeclare package
      Medium = Medium, substanceName="N2")
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{50,-10},{70,10}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Ramp Nm3PerHour(
    height=10,
    duration=10,
    startTime=10)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-140,-2},{-120,18}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant const(k=1)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{70,20},{90,40}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear valve(
    dp_nominal=100000,
    m_flow_nominal=0.03,
    redeclare package Medium = Medium)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{90,-10},{110,10}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Math.Product toMassFlowRate
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-100,4},{-80,24}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RealExpression density(y=rho_normal/3600)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-140,30},{-120,50}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Ramp molarFractionH2(duration=60, startTime=60)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-140,-80},{-120,-60}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant one(k=1)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-140,-50},{-120,-30}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Math.Feedback molarFractionN2 "fractions must sum to one"
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-110,-50},{-90,-30}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Routing.Multiplex2 moleFractions
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-70,-56},{-50,-36}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.RealExpression massFractions[Medium.nX](y=X)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-100,0},{-80,-20}})));
equation 
  connect(massFraction_H2.port_b, massFraction_N2.port_a)
    annotation (Line(points={{30,0},{50,0}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(massFraction_N2.port_b, valve.port_a)
    annotation (Line(points={{70,0},{90,0}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(valve.port_b, boundary1.ports[1])
    annotation (Line(points={{110,0},{120,0}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(const.y, valve.opening)
    annotation (Line(points={{91,30},{100,30},{100,8}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(source.ports[1], volume.ports[1])
    annotation (Line(points={{-40,0},{-11,0},{-11,10}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(massFraction_H2.port_a, volume.ports[2])
    annotation (Line(points={{10,0},{-9,0},{-9,10}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(Nm3PerHour.y, toMassFlowRate.u2)
    annotation (Line(points={{-119,8},{-102,8}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(toMassFlowRate.y, source.m_flow_in) annotation (Line(points={{-79,14},
          {-70,14},{-70,8},{-60,8}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(density.y, toMassFlowRate.u1) annotation (Line(points={{-119,40},{-108,
          40},{-108,20},{-102,20}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(one.y, molarFractionN2.u1)
    annotation (Line(points={{-119,-40},{-108,-40}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(molarFractionH2.y, molarFractionN2.u2) annotation (Line(points={{-119,
          -70},{-100,-70},{-100,-48}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(molarFractionN2.y, moleFractions.u1[1])
    annotation (Line(points={{-91,-40},{-72,-40}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(molarFractionH2.y, moleFractions.u2[1]) annotation (Line(points={{-119,
          -70},{-86,-70},{-86,-52},{-72,-52}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(massFractions.y, source.X_in) annotation (Line(points={{-79,-10},{-70,
          -10},{-70,-4},{-62,-4}}, color={0,0,127}));
  annotation (Diagram(coordinateSystem(extent={{-140,-100},{140,100}}),
        graphics={Line(
          points={{-46,-46},{-34,-46},{-34,-24},{-114,-24},{-114,-10},{-104,-10}},

          color={255,0,0},
          arrow={Arrow.None,Arrow.Filled},
          pattern=LinePattern.Dash)}), experiment(StopTime=500));
end Mixing;
```

**Edit after comment**

It is also possible to separate N2/H2 into two separate sources. A code example and diagram is given below

[image]

```
model Mixing_separateSources
  extends Modelica.Icons.Example;
  package Medium = MixtureGas;

  parameter Medium.AbsolutePressure p_normal=Medium.p_default "Normal pressure";
  parameter Medium.Temperature T_normal=273.15 "Normal temperature";
  parameter Medium.Density rho_normal_N2=Medium.density_pTX(
      p_normal,
      T_normal,
      {1,0}) "Normal density of N2";
  parameter Medium.Density rho_normal_H2=Medium.density_pTX(
      p_normal,
      T_normal,
      {0,1}) "Normal density of H2";

  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T N2(
    use_m_flow_in=true,
    X={1,0},
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    nPorts=1)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-60,-10},{-40,10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT boundary1(nPorts=1, redeclare package
      Medium = Medium)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{140,-10},{120,10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.MassFlowSource_T H2(
    use_m_flow_in=true,
    X={0,1},
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    nPorts=1)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-60,-50},{-40,-30}})));
  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system(energyDynamics=Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.FixedInitial)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-140,40},{-120,60}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.MassFractionsTwoPort massFraction_H2(redeclare package
      Medium = Medium, substanceName="H2")
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{10,-10},{30,10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sensors.MassFractionsTwoPort massFraction_N2(redeclare package
      Medium = Medium, substanceName="N2")
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{50,-10},{70,10}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Math.Gain toMassFlowRate_N2(k=rho_normal_N2/3600)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-100,-2},{-80,18}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Math.Gain toMassFlowRate_H2(k=rho_normal_H2/3600)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-100,-42},{-80,-22}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Ramp N2_Nm3PerHour(
    height=10,
    duration=10,
    startTime=10)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-140,-2},{-120,18}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Ramp H2_Nm3PerHour(
    height=-10,
    duration=10,
    offset=10,
    startTime=10)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-140,-42},{-120,-22}})));
  Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant const(k=1)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{70,20},{90,40}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear valve(
    dp_nominal=100000,
    m_flow_nominal=0.03,
    redeclare package Medium = Medium)
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{90,-10},{110,10}})));
  Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume volume(
    use_portsData=false,
    V=0.1,
    redeclare package Medium = Medium,
    nPorts=3) annotation (Placement(transformation(
        extent={{-10,-10},{10,10}},
        rotation=0,
        origin={-10,20})));
equation 
  connect(massFraction_H2.port_b, massFraction_N2.port_a)
    annotation (Line(points={{30,0},{50,0}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(toMassFlowRate_N2.y, N2.m_flow_in)
    annotation (Line(points={{-79,8},{-60,8}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(toMassFlowRate_H2.y, H2.m_flow_in)
    annotation (Line(points={{-79,-32},{-60,-32}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(H2_Nm3PerHour.y, toMassFlowRate_H2.u)
    annotation (Line(points={{-119,-32},{-102,-32}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(N2_Nm3PerHour.y, toMassFlowRate_N2.u)
    annotation (Line(points={{-119,8},{-102,8}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(massFraction_N2.port_b, valve.port_a)
    annotation (Line(points={{70,0},{90,0}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(valve.port_b, boundary1.ports[1])
    annotation (Line(points={{110,0},{120,0}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(const.y, valve.opening)
    annotation (Line(points={{91,30},{100,30},{100,8}}, color={0,0,127}));
  connect(N2.ports[1], volume.ports[1]) annotation (Line(points={{-40,0},{-11.3333,
          0},{-11.3333,10}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(H2.ports[1], volume.ports[2]) annotation (Line(points={{-40,-40},{-10,
          -40},{-10,10}}, color={0,127,255}));
  connect(massFraction_H2.port_a, volume.ports[3]) annotation (Line(points={{10,
          0},{-8.66667,0},{-8.66667,10}}, color={0,127,255}));
  annotation (Diagram(coordinateSystem(extent={{-140,-100},{140,100}})),
      experiment(StopTime=500, __Dymola_Algorithm="Dassl"));
end Mixing_separateSources;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this give me hope to be able to go further in my simulation with modelica. 
Today I was trying to put the mole to fraction function in the reference_X definition of the mixture gas but I was stucked because reference_X is considered as constant.
I will try your model tomorrow, the next step would be to separate injection of H2 and N2 into two separate massFlowSource. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: I tried your code this evening on my OM platform  OpenModelica v1.20.0 (64-bit)
Connected to OMSimulator v2.1.1.post188-gaf996ad-mingw
Unfortunately, simulation failed with the following message:
The initialization finished successfully without homotopy method.

Wrong boundary mass fractions in medium "MixtureGas" in model "MassFlowSource_T":
The boundary value X_boundary(1) = -2.8028e-09
is negative. It must be positive.

Integrator attempt to handle a problem with a called assert.

Comment: After adding a limiter block between the ramp and the feedback, the simulation succeed!

Comment: It is certainly possible to separate the N2/H2 injection into two sources. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: thanks, this makes the model even more simple

Comment: my model is in progress now, i ama able to combine mutiple volume, control the pressure and fraction. I noticed that for each fluid component I insert, I always need to add manually this "redeclare package Medium = Medium,". Is there a way to configure the component so that this would be part of the parameters?  i saw that when I copy paste from a model to another one usig graphical editor , this redeclare is also missing after paste. is this a bug of OMedit, is it the same  with Dymola?

Comment: I discovered now another problem. I have a long simulation time (more 30 hours because the volume is big and the mixing of H2 & N2 takes time. After running the simulation, i see that some abnormal situation occur after 18 ks, so i try to resimulate from that time after changing some parameter to see if i have a better effect but the Volume H2/N2 mass fraction always restart from the values i defined in my model as the initial values for time = 0, i would expect the simulation to restart from the situation at 18 ks. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: the code definition of my vessel is this:Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume volume(redeclare package Medium = Medium, T_start = TAmb, V = 2*2*casing_length, nPorts = 6, use_HeatTransfer = true, use_portsData = false) and the medium definition is the following : extends MixtureGasNasa(mediumName = "HNx", data = {SingleGasesData.N2, SingleGasesData.H2}, fluidConstants = {FluidData.N2, FluidData.H2}, substanceNames = {"N2", "H2"}, reference_X = moleToMassFractions({0.95, 0.05}, {SingleGasesData.N2.MM, SingleGasesData.H2.MM}));

Comment: I think you should post your two questions (including minimal code example) as two separate questions here on Stack Overflow