# Modelica HNx mixing simulation, initial Mass_fraction as input or parameter

Tags: initialization, modelica

[image]this question refer to the model example given as answer in this previous question
[Modelica fluid mixing simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75453900/modelica-fluid-mixing-simulation/75458311#75458311)
In the example, the initial mass fraction are defined in the Medium definition:

```
package MixtureGas "Mixture gas"
  extends Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.MixtureGasNasa(
    mediumName="MixtureGas",
data={Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.SingleGasesData.N2,Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.SingleGasesData.H2},
    fluidConstants={Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.FluidData.N2,Modelica.Media.IdealGases.Common.FluidData.H2},
    substanceNames={"N2","H2"},
    reference_X={0.4,0.6});
end MixtureGas;
```

when i simulate the model Mixing_separateSource given in the same post on a 200 s simulation time, it works well. If i want to resimulated from time 100 to 200, i would expect the simulation to restart from the mass fraction stored in the result Mixing_separateSource.mat for the time 100s but it seems to restart always from Reference_X
Is it a strange behaviour of OpenModelical or a normal Modelica behaviour?

A workaround could be to be able to give initial values for mass fraction as parameter of my mixing volume submodel.
When i define {0.8,0.2} as X_Start in the Initialize folder of my Vessel parameter, and run the simulation, it  starts from {0.4,0.6}.

[Edit ]Digging more on this subject this afternoon, i discovered that the volume medium mass fraction are well initialized but not the massfraction measurement. see the plot picture. How is it possible?
[edit2]
[image: resimulate from 50s]
the second picture show that OpenModelica restart the simulation at 50s but with the initial values, no the states from the previous simulation

[edit3] I further investigated by activating resimulate from a result file at time 100s. The Init loc show that init variable are properly read but that a lot of Port config are using the default_Xi or reference_X constants for their initialization process.
extract from media modelica standard library:

```
partial package PartialMedium
  "Partial medium properties (base package of all media packages)"
  extends Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types;
  extends Modelica.Icons.MaterialPropertiesPackage;

  // Constants to be set in Medium
  constant Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Choices.IndependentVariables
    ThermoStates "Enumeration type for independent variables";
  constant String mediumName="unusablePartialMedium" "Name of the medium";
  constant String substanceNames[:]={mediumName}
    "Names of the mixture substances. Set substanceNames={mediumName} if only one substance.";
  constant String extraPropertiesNames[:]=fill("", 0)
    "Names of the additional (extra) transported properties. Set extraPropertiesNames=fill(\"\",0) if unused";
  constant Boolean singleState
    "= true, if u and d are not a function of pressure";
  constant Boolean reducedX=true
    "= true if medium contains the equation sum(X) = 1.0; set reducedX=true if only one substance (see docu for details)";
  constant Boolean fixedX=false
    "= true if medium contains the equation X = reference_X";
  constant AbsolutePressure reference_p=101325
    "Reference pressure of Medium: default 1 atmosphere";
  constant Temperature reference_T=298.15
    "Reference temperature of Medium: default 25 deg Celsius";
  constant MassFraction reference_X[nX]=fill(1/nX, nX)
    "Default mass fractions of medium";
  constant AbsolutePressure p_default=101325
    "Default value for pressure of medium (for initialization)";
  constant Temperature T_default=Modelica.Units.Conversions.from_degC(20)
    "Default value for temperature of medium (for initialization)";
  constant SpecificEnthalpy h_default=specificEnthalpy_pTX(
          p_default,
          T_default,
          X_default)
    "Default value for specific enthalpy of medium (for initialization)";
  constant MassFraction X_default[nX]=reference_X
    "Default value for mass fractions of medium (for initialization)";
  constant ExtraProperty C_default[nC]=fill(0, nC)
    "Default value for trace substances of medium (for initialization)";

  final constant Integer nS=size(substanceNames, 1) "Number of substances";
  constant Integer nX=nS "Number of mass fractions";
  constant Integer nXi=if fixedX then 0 else if reducedX then nS - 1 else nS
    "Number of structurally independent mass fractions (see docu for details)";

  final constant Integer nC=size(extraPropertiesNames, 1)
    "Number of extra (outside of standard mass-balance) transported properties";
  constant Real C_nominal[nC](min=fill(Modelica.Constants.eps, nC)) = 1.0e-6*
    ones(nC) "Default for the nominal values for the extra properties";
  replaceable record FluidConstants =
      Modelica.Media.Interfaces.Types.Basic.FluidConstants
    "Critical, triple, molecular and other standard data of fluid";

  replaceable record ThermodynamicState
    "Minimal variable set that is available as input argument to every medium function"
    extends Modelica.Icons.Record;
  end ThermodynamicState;

  replaceable partial model BaseProperties
    "Base properties (p, d, T, h, u, R_s, MM and, if applicable, X and Xi) of a medium"
    InputAbsolutePressure p "Absolute pressure of medium";
    InputMassFraction[nXi] Xi(start=reference_X[1:nXi])
      "Structurally independent mass fractions";
    InputSpecificEnthalpy h "Specific enthalpy of medium";
    Density d "Density of medium";
    Temperature T "Temperature of medium";
    MassFraction[nX] X(start=reference_X)
      "Mass fractions (= (component mass)/total mass  m_i/m)";
    SpecificInternalEnergy u "Specific internal energy of medium";
    SpecificHeatCapacity R_s "Gas constant (of mixture if applicable)";
    MolarMass MM "Molar mass (of mixture or single fluid)";
    ThermodynamicState state
      "Thermodynamic state record for optional functions";
    parameter Boolean preferredMediumStates=false
      "= true if StateSelect.prefer shall be used for the independent property variables of the medium"
      annotation (Evaluate=true, Dialog(tab="Advanced"));
    parameter Boolean standardOrderComponents=true
      "If true, and reducedX = true, the last element of X will be computed from the other ones";
    Modelica.Units.NonSI.Temperature_degC T_degC=
        Modelica.Units.Conversions.to_degC(T)
      "Temperature of medium in [degC]";
    Modelica.Units.NonSI.Pressure_bar p_bar=
        Modelica.Units.Conversions.to_bar(p)
      "Absolute pressure of medium in [bar]";
```

My fear is that this mixture gas model was not developped in a perspective of having a variable mixture between two gas component in the context of a simulation.

```
C:/Users/ruwp/AppData/Local/Temp/OpenModelica/OMEdit/HNx_Pack.Mixing_separateSources/Mixing_separateSources.exe -port=63833 -logFormat=xmltcp -override=startTime=0,stopTime=200,stepSize=1,tolerance=1e-06,solver=dassl,outputFormat=mat,variableFilter=.* -r=C:/Users/ruwp/AppData/Local/Temp/OpenModelica/OMEdit/HNx_Pack.Mixing_separateSources/Mixing_separateSources_res.mat -iif=C:/Users/ruwp/Documents/RD/simulation/OModel/appli/Initial.mat -iit=100 -w -lv=LOG_INIT,LOG_INIT_HOMOTOPY,LOG_INIT_V,LOG_STATS -inputPath=C:/Users/ruwp/AppData/Local/Temp/OpenModelica/OMEdit/HNx_Pack.Mixing_separateSources -outputPath=C:/Users/ruwp/AppData/Local/Temp/OpenModelica/OMEdit/HNx_Pack.Mixing_separateSources
### START INITIALIZATION ###
updating min-values
updating max-values
updating nominal-values
updating primary start-values
...
updated start value: volume.medium.Xi[2](start=0.2)
updated start value: volume.medium.Xi[1](start=0.8)
...
import start values
file: C:/Users/ruwp/Documents/RD/simulation/OModel/appli/Initial.mat
time: 100
import real variables
...
| volume.medium.Xi[1](start=0.990077)
| volume.medium.Xi[2](start=0.00992328)
...

| massFraction_H2.Xi(start=0.188464)
| massFraction_H2.port_a.Xi_outflow[1](start=0.4)
| massFraction_H2.port_a.Xi_outflow[2](start=0.6)
| massFraction_H2.port_b.Xi_outflow[1](start=0.990077)
| massFraction_H2.port_b.Xi_outflow[2](start=0.00992328)
| massFraction_N2.Xi(start=0.811536)
| massFraction_N2.port_a.Xi_outflow[1](start=0.4)
| massFraction_N2.port_a.Xi_outflow[2](start=0.6)
| massFraction_N2.port_b.Xi_outflow[1](start=0.990077)
| massFraction_N2.port_b.Xi_outflow[2](start=0.00992328)
...
| volume.mXi[1](start=0.0991431)
| volume.mXi[2](start=0.000993685)
...
import real parameters
...
| boundary1.X[1](start=0.4)
| boundary1.X[2](start=0.6)
| boundary1.X_in_internal[1](start=0.4)
| boundary1.X_in_internal[2](start=0.6)
| boundary1.medium.T(start=293.15)
| boundary1.medium.X[1](start=0.4)
| boundary1.medium.X[2](start=0.6)
| boundary1.medium.Xi[1](start=0.4)
| boundary1.medium.Xi[2](start=0.6)
| boundary1.medium.p(start=101325)
| boundary1.medium.state.T(start=293.15)
| boundary1.medium.state.X[1](start=0.4)
| boundary1.medium.state.X[2](start=0.6)
| boundary1.medium.state.p(start=101325)
| boundary1.p(start=101325)
| boundary1.p_in_internal(start=101325)
| boundary1.ports[1].Xi_outflow[1](start=0.4)
| boundary1.ports[1].Xi_outflow[2](start=0.6)
...
| valve.m_flow_start(start=0)
| valve.opening(start=1)
| valve.port_a.Xi_outflow[1](start=0.4)
| valve.port_a.Xi_outflow[2](start=0.6)
| valve.port_b.p(start=101325)
| valve.state_b.X[1](start=0.4)
| valve.state_b.X[2](start=0.6)
| valve.state_b.p(start=101325)
| volume.T_start(start=500)
| volume.V(start=0.1)
| volume.X_start[1](start=0.8)
| volume.X_start[2](start=0.2)
| volume.fluidLevel_max(start=1)
...
import real discrete
...
initialization method: symbolic        [solves the initialization problem symbolically - default]
Model contains homotopy operator: Use adaptive homotopy method to solve initialization problem. To disable initialization with homotopy operator use "-noHomotopyOnFirstTry".
parameter values
real parameters
...
[49] parameter Real boundary1.X[1](start=0.4, fixed=true) = 0.4
[50] parameter Real boundary1.X[2](start=0.6, fixed=true) = 0.6
[51] parameter Real boundary1.X_in_internal[1](start=0.4, fixed=true) = 0.4
[52] parameter Real boundary1.X_in_internal[2](start=0.6, fixed=true) = 0.6
[53] parameter Real boundary1.medium.T(start=293.15, fixed=true) = 293.15
[54] parameter Real boundary1.medium.X[1](start=0.4, fixed=true) = 0.4
[55] parameter Real boundary1.medium.X[2](start=0.6, fixed=true) = 0.6
[56] parameter Real boundary1.medium.Xi[1](start=0.4, fixed=true) = 0.4
[57] parameter Real boundary1.medium.Xi[2](start=0.6, fixed=true) = 0.6
[58] parameter Real boundary1.medium.p(start=101325, fixed=true) = 101325
[59] parameter Real boundary1.medium.state.T(start=293.15, fixed=true) = 293.15
[60] parameter Real boundary1.medium.state.X[1](start=0.4, fixed=true) = 0.4
[61] parameter Real boundary1.medium.state.X[2](start=0.6, fixed=true) = 0.6
[62] parameter Real boundary1.medium.state.p(start=101325, fixed=true) = 101325
[63] parameter Real boundary1.p(start=101325, fixed=true) = 101325
[64] parameter Real boundary1.p_in_internal(start=101325, fixed=true) = 101325
[65] parameter Real boundary1.ports[1].Xi_outflow[1](start=0.4, fixed=true) = 0.4
[66] parameter Real boundary1.ports[1].Xi_outflow[2](start=0.6, fixed=true) = 0.6
[67] parameter Real boundary1.ports[1].p(start=101325, fixed=true) = 101325
...
[96] parameter Real valve.port_a.Xi_outflow[1](start=0.4, fixed=true) = 0.4
[97] parameter Real valve.port_a.Xi_outflow[2](start=0.6, fixed=true) = 0.6
[98] parameter Real valve.port_b.p(start=101325, fixed=true) = 101325
[99] parameter Real valve.state_b.X[1](start=0.4, fixed=true) = 0.4
[100] parameter Real valve.state_b.X[2](start=0.6, fixed=true) = 0.6
[101] parameter Real valve.state_b.p(start=101325, fixed=true) = 101325
[102] parameter Real volume.T_start(start=500, fixed=true) = 500
[103] parameter Real volume.V(start=0.1, fixed=true) = 0.1
[104] parameter Real volume.X_start[1](start=0.8, fixed=true) = 0.8
[105] parameter Real volume.X_start[2](start=0.2, fixed=true) = 0.2
...
integer parameters
...
boolean parameters
...
string parameters
[1] parameter String massFraction_H2.substanceName(start="H2") = "H2"
[2] parameter String massFraction_N2.substanceName(start="N2") = "N2"
### SOLUTION OF THE INITIALIZATION ###
states variables
[1] Real volume.medium.T(start=329.067, nominal=500) = 500 (pre: 329.067)
[2] Real volume.medium.Xi[1](start=0.990077, nominal=0.1) = 0.8 (pre: 0.990077)
[3] Real volume.medium.Xi[2](start=0.00992328, nominal=0.1) = 0.2 (pre: 0.00992328)
[4] Real volume.medium.p(start=110318, nominal=1e+06) = 101375 (pre: 110318)
derivatives variables
[5] Real der(volume.medium.T) = -4.67691 (pre: -1.04633)
[6] Real der(volume.medium.Xi[1]) = -0.0104721 (pre: 0.000344037)
[7] Real der(volume.medium.Xi[2]) = 0.0104721 (pre: -0.000344037)
[8] Real der(volume.medium.p) = 4124.17 (pre: 67.8659)
other real variables
...
[48] Real massFraction_H2.Xi(start=0.188464, nominal=1) = 0.39955 (pre: 0.188464)
[49] Real massFraction_H2.port_a.Xi_outflow[1](start=0.4, nominal=0.1) = 0.4 (pre: 0.4)
[50] Real massFraction_H2.port_a.Xi_outflow[2](start=0.6, nominal=0.1) = 0.6 (pre: 0.6)
[51] Real massFraction_H2.port_b.Xi_outflow[1](start=0.990077, nominal=0.1) = 0.8 (pre: 0.990077)
[52] Real massFraction_H2.port_b.Xi_outflow[2](start=0.00992328, nominal=0.1) = 0.2 (pre: 0.00992328)
[53] Real massFraction_N2.Xi(start=0.811536, nominal=1) = 0.60045 (pre: 0.811536)
[54] Real massFraction_N2.port_a.Xi_outflow[1](start=0.4, nominal=0.1) = 0.4 (pre: 0.4)
[55] Real massFraction_N2.port_a.Xi_outflow[2](start=0.6, nominal=0.1) = 0.6 (pre: 0.6)
[56] Real massFraction_N2.port_b.Xi_outflow[1](start=0.990077, nominal=0.1) = 0.8 (pre: 0.990077)
[57] Real massFraction_N2.port_b.Xi_outflow[2](start=0.00992328, nominal=0.1) = 0.2 (pre: 0.00992328)
...
[72] Real volume.mXi[1](start=0.0991431, nominal=1) = 0.0152682 (pre: 0.0991431)
[73] Real volume.mXi[2](start=0.000993685, nominal=1) = 0.00381704 (pre: 0.000993685)
...
boolean variables
...
```

We can see that  a lot of start condition related to mass fractions are linked to the 0.4 / 0.6 values that are defined as Reference_X.
Reference_X and Default_X are Constant, so impossible to change them when i extend the HNx GasMixture package. Would it be possible to define them as parameters or input that can be defined for each instance of the media?

[ edit4]

My first idea was to change the reference_X definition and base it on a parameter but it was refused by the translation rule: reference_X is a constant and cannot be defined by a parameter….
Later yesterday, I tried to change the gasMixture definition by relating reference_X to one constant (H2 rate) . This was accepted by the syntax checking and I could define different mixture with 10% of H2, 50%, 90%) .
I tried to simulate my full model starting with 50% HNx, but it did not work properly and OMEDit crashed during configuration of plot.

I need to check how to reactivate plot interface on an old simulation result or find a way to easy plot data from old result with other tools than OMEDit..
This is really difficult when I need to analyse data at the same time that are in a completely different range. I did not find a good way to zoom on multiple graph together, this is for me the base of simulation analysis. So I loose a lot of time on this bad working of OMEDit plot GUI, with no way to save plot and too many crashes of OMEDit.

I will investigate python to draw curve based on .mat or CSV files.

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the normal "handling" is that you need to give the initial value as the final value from the simulation before, as you describe aa s work around.

The "administration" of how to perform simulation may vary from each vendor of Modelica and is not part of the Modelica standard.

I usually do simulations using FMUs in a Python environment and I have the same need as you have and implemented a "help function" to automate the transfer of final values to initial values for the next simulation. There is in the standard around FMU a way to read-out all the continuous time states, and is a good help.

In OpenModelica I am not sure if there is a way to facilitate what you want to do. There is in the menu to the right, above the variable section, a panel with knobs: restart, run, and stop, which perhaps try to meet your need, but it can also be that it is related to animation. Someone else need to fill in here.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I was considering also to use the pysimulator  (is is what you use?) in order to be able to keep code of the plot i need (OMEditor  is not able to do it). Openmodlica has some resimulate capacity but they seems not working properly on my model.

Comment: I use PyFMI from Modelon AB, and you find this software at Github.

Comment: I try to reproduce your results using the corrected model by Rene Just Nielsen, but I have some difficulties. Is it exactly that model you use? Which version of OpenModelica and  Modelica Standard Library is it? (I myself tried OM 1.20 with MSL 4.0). I happen to have identical initial values (0.6) for massFraction_H2.Xi and volume.medium.Xi[2] and similarly (0.4) for massFraction_N2.Xi and volume.mediium.Xi[1]. Further simulation stops at 120 with exit code 255.

Comment: You are right, during my investigation, i changed the init Mass fraction on the volume only to {0.8,0.2}, My MSL verson is 4.0.0s  with OM 1.20., so the volume configuration was changed this way:
```
Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume volume(redeclare package Medium = Medium, T_start = 500, V = 0.1, X_start = {0.8, 0.2}, nPorts = 3, p_start = 101375, use_portsData = false)
```

Comment: Good we have the same software framework.  The code your posted here partial package PartialMedium is truncated and I do not understand where the code in your comment belong.

Comment: In the Mixing separate sources model from Rene Just Nielsen  given in the other post, all components are defined with an additional « redeclare Package Medium= Medium ». One of the component is the closedVolume. In this class, there is the possibility to give start condition on the mass fraction … so my idea was that forcing this volume to start with a mass fraction different from the reference_X given in the gasMixture definition would allow me to start my simulation from another state. This s why I tried to set X_Start as {0.8,0.2} for the volume